# Using a qtip on a ExtJS 4 TreePanel column?

Tags: extjs4.1

In the column definition I used `tooltip: 'some text'`, but it didn't get shown.
Only after I switched to `tooltipType: 'title'` is this a browser specific bug or a bug in ExtJS 4.1.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [default](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-tooltipType) `tooltipType` is `qtip`. For which to show you need to call

```
Ext.QuickTips.init();
```

Most probably in the `application.launch()` method.